# Cheese from Denmark

Tags: knowledge, cipher

You'll need "cheese from denmark" for this cipher puzzle.

> Denmark
>
> Portugal 1/2
>
> France "hello"

> ?AI EBOM AEEDY EHT SEOU EPNHS TNHG OS EPNHS "F" AN AI SEBOM SSEHÆ AI THWIAK EHT

**ANSWER: 8-P A _ _ _ _ _ _ _**

Comment: rot13(NV nccrnef znal gvzrf va gur frpbaq zrffntr, naq gur ynfg jbeq nccrnef gb or gur fcryyrq onpxjneqf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer:

> 8 P(ointed) ASTERISK!

Reasoning:
Starting with the cipher:

The repeated occurrence of

> 'THE' backwards and '?' at the beginning suggests the text is a question asked backwards.  Reversing the text gives:
>  THE KAIWHT IA ÆHESS MOBES IA NA "F" SHNPE SO GHNT SHNPE UOES THE YDEEA MOBE IA?
>  The repetition of "THE" and "IA" suggests a standard cryptogram with T,H,E, and likely S standing for themselves. Tweaking it a bit yields:
>  THE KNIGHT IN CHESS MOVES IN AN "L" SHAPE SO WHAT SHAPE DOES THE QUEEN MOVE IN?
>  With key
>  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆ
>  NVÆUELWHIJKFMAOPYRSTDBGXQZC
>  with reversible/2-way encoding.

ANSWER: 8-P A _ _ _ _ _ _ _

> A queen moves in the shape of an 8-pointed star, or octogram, or to fit the blanks here, an
>  8 P(ointed) ASTERISK

> For the top, presumably the answers to the clues help solve the cipher or clue something like "cryptogram". I had some ideas, but nothing that made much sense. Fortunately, @Gahja has cracked the case!  Gahja notes:
>  Danish (Denmark) + Port (1/2 of Portugal) + Salut (French hello) is "Danish Port Salut", which is a cheese from Denmark also known as "[ESROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esrom)".
>  ESROM is "MORSE" reversed, which explains how the cipher was created.
>  Each letter is substituted with the letter that is its reverse when in Morse Code. For example, A=N because A= .- and N= -.
>  T=T because T= - which reverses to itself.
>  C=Æ because C= -.-. and Æ= .-.- , etc.
>  This allows us to recover the full cipher alphabet even for unclued letters:
>  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆ
>  NVÆUELWHIÖKFMAOPYRSTDBGXQÜC

Comment: rot13 (1/2 Cbeghtny vf Cbeg, Senapr uryyb vf Fnyhg nf lbh fhttrfgrq naq gur "Qnavfu Cbeg-Fnyhg" vf Rfebz (n purffr). Jvgu fcryyf "Zbefr" onpxjneqf.) Maybe that makes any sense for your solution.

Comment: That does make sense. I never would have figured that out. I'll add it in. @Gahja